# Why is there a conflict between variables and functions of the same name in JScript?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, javascript, jscript.net

I have a variable named age and a function named AGE.  Ignore the problem I am having with JScript beign case insensitive at the moment, i.e. age(dob) and AGE(dob) both work...

Why does JScript try to use the age variable as a function?  My best guess would be that jScript is treating the function declaration as both declaration and expression...

```
function AGE(birthDate) { 
     return cmd.Age(birthDate); 
};


var age = 32;
var foo = age; // Error on AGE function
```

I am using the ScriptControlClass in a C# application and using JScript as a simple embedded language to provide some simple-medium complexity expression to my user base...

Comment: JavaScript becomes a lot easier to understand if you stop using the "function foo() {...}" syntax, and start using the "var foo = function() {...}" form. Suddenly the fact that functions are objects that you reference in the same way as anything becomes clear, and opens up lambda-style coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard JavaScript syntax, described in summary on this [JavaScript tips](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html) page. You should take a look at a JavaScript reference; many people recommend [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748), written by the original author of JavaScript, but you should do your research before buying a book.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't give a function and a variable the same name. If you have a variable called my_cat and a function called my_cat, JavaScript will forget either what the function's supposed to do or what value you've stored in the my_cat variable. Because of this weird behavior, and because function names are case sensitive, it makes sense to have a different convention for naming functions than for naming variables.

Comment: I have no control over what my users will try, which is how I ran itno this problem.  Of course having my function in all UPPER case was supposed to avoid conflicts...

Comment: Your Users are now your developers WOOO HOOOO!  :)

Comment: Well, my users are data interface specialists whoms job is the clean client data into something reasonable to process. :)  So they were part developers already.  It was actually their request to migrate from XBASE expressions to JavaScript...  However, the migration is lookin ugly so far...

Answer (score 2):

In JScript/javascript, functions are first class objects.  So, *functions are also variables* that you can pass around, reuse, replace, etc.

That should explain why you can't do this.  On the line with the error, it's not clear what you're assigning to foo: it could be age, the numeric variable with a value of 32.  But it could also be age, the function variable.

Put another way, this is perfectly legal:

```
function age(birthDate) { 
   return cmd.Age(birthDate); 
};

var d = new Date();
var foo = age;
foo(d);
```

and so is this:

```
function print42() {
    return 42;
}

print42 = function() {
    return 32;
}

print42(); //legal - returns 32
```

If you're worried about avoided conflicts, you could try putting your functions inside an *object* instead:

```
var $$MyProjectName = function()  { 
    var MyFunctionName = function() {
        // do something
    }

}

// later
var $$MyProjectInstance = new $$MyProjectName();
$$MyProjectInstance.MyFunctionName();
```

Note the '$' in the names.  There's nothing special there.  '$' is perfectly fine for use as part of an identifier name, and you want to make sure your name is unique.  However, thanks to jQuery and the like the $ "secret" is starting to get out, and so you want to also add a little something extra to keep things unique.